For what theories are submodels closed for intersection?
The theories coming from a variety in the sense of universal algebra are a known example. Fields and ordered groups are important examples not covered by universal algebra. I also believe models of ZFC have this property but not sure.
On the other hand, it can fail for very simple theories like the following one: empty signature and an axiom stating existence of two unequal elements. Then $\{0,1,2\}$ is a model of this theory, $\{0,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ are submodels, but their intersection is not a model.
What are some conditions, more general than being the theory corresponding to some variety of universal algebra, that guarantee closure for finite or arbitrary intersections of submodels?

Consider a theory axiomatized by sentences of the form $\forall x_1,\dots,\forall x_n,\exists!y,\phi$ where $\phi$ is quantifier-free. Unless I've made a mistake, such a theory has the property you asked about.

It may be interesting to note that, if you restrict to complete theories and elementary submodels the question has a simple and elegant answer:Theories such that all algebraically closed subsets of a model are elementary submodels.

This problem was solved by Michael Rabin in the paper

Classes of models and sets of sentences with the intersection property
Ann. Fac. Sci. Univ. Clermont-Ferrand 7 (1962), 39–53.

which is available on Numdam.
Rabin's characterization is somewhat complicated, so I won't reproduce it here. The basic idea is that such a theory must be $\forall\exists$-axiomatizable, but with an extra uniqueness condition on the witnesses to the existential quantifiers. Making the right kind of uniqueness condition precise is the difficulty.
As Andreas Blass points out in the comments, a theory axiomatized by sentences of the form $\forall x_1\dots \forall x_n\exists^! y\, \varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)$ where $\varphi$ is quantifier-free will satisfy the uniqueness condition. But not every intersection-closed theory has this form.
The problem appears as Exercise 5.2.12 in Model Theory by Chang and Keisler, where it is double starred to indicate that it is extremely difficult.
Chang and Keisler prove in the text (Theorem 5.2.16) that if a sentence is preserved under intersections of descending chains of submodels, then it is equivalent to a $\forall\exists$ sentence. Exercises 5.2.10 through 5.2.18 are all relevant.
